# Custom font icon not rendering properly in chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, font-face, glyphicons

I have used [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/) to generate my custom font icon ttf and created font face using it.

While using it in chrome some times i'm getting invalid fonts instead of the actual fonts.

[image: font icon with issue]

[image: font icon without issue]

While checking the font family of the invalid characters it applies "Times New Roman" font family.

[image]

Note: This issue occurs only when we load the css and fonts from the CDN.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the browser unable to read the font icons as a UTF-8 encoded character since the style sheets are fed without content type from the CDN.

I have set the response content type as `text/css;charset=UTF-8` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is happening because its from the CDN , then its an issue with the CDN not being available, or the font is not propagated to all the servers for the CDN.

you should, as backup, host the font files on your server.

Comment: is the CDN being served over https://  in your import? Chrome will not work properly if your import isn't over https://

also, you should be backing up your fonts to your local server in case CDN fails.